# Error bars disappear in ListLogPlot when some points can't be plotted

Tags: plotting

**Bug introduced in Mathematica 12.0**?

I'm having a problem: *all* the error bars disappear in `ListLogPlot`,`ListLogLinearPlot`, and `ListLogLogPlot` when I ask them to plot lists that include points that can't be plotted, for instance because the coordinate that's supposed to be log-transformed is non-positive.

Simple example:

```
points = Table[2^i {1, Around[1, 0.5]}, {i, 1, 8, 3}];
pointsx0 = Table[{2^i - 1, 2^i Around[1, 0.5]}, {i, 0, 8, 3}];
pointsy0 = Table[{2^i, Around[(2^i - 4), 2^(i - 1)]}, {i, 2, 8, 3}];
```

`ListPlot[{points, pointsx0, pointsy0}]` works perfectly:
[image: ListPlot shows error bars]

But `ListLogPlot`, `ListLogLinearPlot`, and `ListLogLogPLot` don't show any error bars, even for the list `points` where all the elements can be plotted:
[image: No error bars]

Obviously I can handle this ad hoc by filtering out points that are causing problems, but this seems like a bug – shouldn't these functions be doing this automatically? Am I missing something?

Comment: Very odd. Take a look at the output from `Show[{ListLogPlot[points], ListLogPlot[pointsx0], 
  ListLogPlot[pointsy0]}]`

Comment: @RohitNamjoshi in that case, `points` and `pointsx0` are both shown with error bars, but `pointsy0` is shown without, since it has a point that can't be shown by `ListLogPlot`. In other words, the behavior is consistent with what happens without the `Show` wrapper.

Comment: File it with Wolfram, in my opinion